# How to summarize a column of dates with the values

Tags: excel-formula

I have a three columns as below in excel

[image]

I want as below

[image]

can someone suggest me formula for the above

Comment: Isn't that just a pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more is Pivot I have attached 2 answers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First remove duplicates from the column you want to sum up and then you can use `Sumifs()` function with the criteria. This is one method I hope this helped your query

[image]